# Solve the system of equations $\frac{x}{3} + \frac{y}{2} = \frac{2x}{3} - \frac{y}{6} = 7$ for $x$ and $y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the problem. The answer is suppose to be x = 12, y = 6

$$\frac{ x }{3} + \frac{y}{2} = \frac{ 2x }{3} - \frac{ y }{6} = 7$$

I've tried this. I'm having trouble figuring out what do on the last step I will describe.

$$6 • \frac{ x }{3} + \frac{y}{2} = \frac{ 2x }{3} - \frac{ y }{6} = 7$$

$$2x + 3y = 4x - y = 42$$

$$2x - 4y = 42$$

$$4y = 42 - 2x$$

$$y = \frac{ 42 - 2x}{4}$$

$$2x + 3[ \frac{ 42 - 2x }{4} ] = 7$$

Comment: You had 2x + 3y =  42 : how does it change into 7?

Comment: As of right now I don't know how it changes back into 7, but I have solved problems close to these, and as far as I know that's the right way..

Comment: It is not true that $2x - 4y = 42$.  When you obtained $2x - 4y$ by subtracting $2x + 3y$ from $4x - y$, you should have obtained $2x - 4y = 0$.

Comment: The point is that it _doesn't change_ into 7: you have a copying error in your last line, apart from the error **N. F. Tassig** addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really given two equations here:
$$
\left\{\begin{align}
  \frac{x}{3} + \frac{y}{2} &= 7\\[0.3cm]
  \frac{2x}{3} - \frac{y}{6} &= 7
\end{align}
\right.
$$

Multiply the first equation by 6 to get $2x + 3y = 42$.  Multiply the second equation by 6 to get $4x - y = 42$.

$$
\left\{
\begin{align} \displaystyle
  2x + 3y &= 42\\
  4x - y &= 42
\end{align}
\right.
$$

Multiply the second equation by $3$ and add it to the first equation to end up with $14x = 168$, and so $x = 12$.  Then use either equation to get $y = 6$.

Comment: The answer is supposed to be x = 12, y = 6

Comment: Let me edit real quick.  Brainfart.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is linked to how you deal with the two equations (As there are two equal signs you have two equations described in one line). So when you do the following you change from two equations to only one and introduce a mistake when doing so.

Quote:
$$2x + 3y = 4x - y = 42$$

$$2x - 4y = 42$$

Firstly you have turned two equations into only one and secondly you have not performed the same operation to all sides of the operation. You have subtracted $2x+3y$ so your working should have looked like:

$$2x + 3y = 4x - y = 42$$

$$0=2x - 4y = 42-2x-3y$$

This maintains you have two equations. As a side note it is more generally advisable to work with each equation separately rather than join them together as you have done as you normally want to do different things with each.

Following on from the line above you need to split it into two equations:

$$0=2x-4y \text{  and  } 0=42-2x-3y$$
$$x=2y \text{  and  } 0=42-2x-3y$$
Subbing the first into the second gives:
$$0=42-4y-3y$$
$$7y=42$$
$$y=6$$
Subbing this back into the earlier equation $x=2y$ gives:
$$x=12$$

Answer (score 2):

$6·\left[\frac{x}3+\frac{y}2=7\right]$
$18·\left[\frac{2x}3-\frac{y}6=7\right]$
$====================$
then ...

Comment: Why 18 and not 12?

Comment: @W.Zlacki  Multiplying the first equation by $6$ and the second equation by $18$ enables you to eliminate $y$ when you add the resulting equations.